# Laravels messes the creation/selection of columns that are defined as SET of integers

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, set, laravel-query-builder

The column `choice_number` defined as:

```php
    $table->set('choice_number', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

```sql
mysql> SHOW columns FROM choices;
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| choice_number | set('1','2','3','4') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
...
+---------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

My issue appears when I insert rows that pick the `SET` values `3` or `4` using **Laravel** and they get stored respectively as `1,2` and `3`.

## The weird behavior

```php
>>> \App\Models\Choice::create(['question_id' => 4, 'content' => "lorem ipsum1", 'is_correct' => 0, 'choice_number'=> 3]);
=> App\Models\Choice {#4468
     question_id: 4,
     content: "lorem ipsum1",
     is_correct: 0,
     choice_number: 3,
     updated_at: "2022-03-13 21:44:31",
     created_at: "2022-03-13 21:44:31",
     id: 18,
   }
>>> \App\Models\Choice::create(['question_id' => 4, 'content' => "lorem ipsum1", 'is_correct' => 0, 'choice_number'=> 4]);
=> App\Models\Choice {#4460
     question_id: 4,
     content: "lorem ipsum1",
     is_correct: 0,
     choice_number: 4,
     updated_at: "2022-03-13 21:44:53",
     created_at: "2022-03-13 21:44:53",
     id: 19,
   }
```

```php
>>> \App\Models\Choice::whereIn('id', [18, 19])->pluck('choice_number');
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4469
     all: [
       "1,2",
       "3",
     ],
   }
```

```sql
mysql> SELECT id, question_id, choice_number, is_correct FROM choices;
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
| id | question_id | choice_number | is_correct |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 | 1             |          0 |
|  2 |           1 | 2             |          0 |
|  3 |           1 | 1,2           |          0 |
|  4 |           1 | 3             |          1 |
|  5 |           2 | 1             |          0 |
|  6 |           2 | 2             |          0 |
|  7 |           2 | 1,2           |          1 |
|  8 |           2 | 3             |          0 |
|  9 |           3 | 1             |          0 |
| 10 |           3 | 2             |          1 |
| 11 |           3 | 1,2           |          0 |
| 12 |           3 | 3             |          0 |
| 13 |           4 | 1             |          0 |
| 14 |           4 | 2             |          1 |
| 15 |           4 | 1,2           |          0 |
| 16 |           4 | 3             |          0 |
| 18 |           4 | 1,2           |          0 |
| 19 |           4 | 3             |          0 |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Casting the column to int

#### MySQL does it correctly

```sql
mysql> SELECT id, question_id, choice_number, is_correct, CAST(choice_number AS INT) FROM choices;
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+----------------------------+
| id | question_id | choice_number | is_correct | CAST(choice_number AS INT) |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+----------------------------+
...
| 13 |           4 | 1             |          0 |                          1 |
| 14 |           4 | 2             |          1 |                          2 |
| 15 |           4 | 1,2           |          0 |                          3 |
| 16 |           4 | 3             |          0 |                          4 |
| 18 |           4 | 1,2           |          0 |                          3 |
| 19 |           4 | 3             |          0 |                          4 |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+----------------------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Eloquent messes it up

No need to make the post longer. `"1,2"` turns to `1` and `"3"` stays `3`.